# What is the exact difference between both the hitTest methods

Tags: flash

What is the exact difference between mc1.hitTest(mc2) and mc1.hitTest(mc2._x,mc2._y,true)

Comment: the first one just uses bounding rectangles to determine a hit, while the second, uses the shape/contour of an object to determine if the other is within (hits it) or not.

Comment: hmm..is there any way i can detect  a collision which will occur in the future?

Comment: @George that should be an answer - look at the sole answer given as of now: I went what the <name of answerer> upon reading it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one just uses bounding rectangles to determine a hit, while the second, uses the shape/contour of an object to determine if the other is within (hits it) or not.

Regarding a way to 'detect a collision which will occur in the future', if the velocity of your object is constant, you should be able to.

[Seb Lee-Delisle](http://sebleedelisle.com) has two interesting posts on this:

- [Predictive collision detection techniques](http://sebleedelisle.com/2010/01/predictive-collision-detection-techniques/)
- [Predicting circle line collisions](http://sebleedelisle.com/2010/01/predicting-circle-line-collisions/)

HTH

Answer (score -1):

1st one takes MovieClip as its single parameter, and the second one takes two Numbers and a Boolean.